# Combine data frames and add file name with PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about PANDAS.
I have many dataframes like below.

[image]

I would like to combine these dataframes and add file name as right figure.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of list of `DataFrames` with parameter `keys` for df names, then remove `MultiIndex` and create new column `File`:

```
dfs = [df1,df2, df3]
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=range(1, len(dfs) + 1))
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename_axis('File')
       .reset_index()
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['a','b','c'],
                   'Price':[4,5,6]})

print (df1)

   Price Product
0      4       a
1      5       b
2      6       c

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['d','e','g'],
                   'Price':[9,8,7]})

print (df2)
   Price Product
0      9       d
1      8       e
2      7       g

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['f','z','h'],
                   'Price':[1,2,4]})

print (df3)
   Price Product
0      1       f
1      2       z
2      4       h
```

```
dfs = [df1,df2, df3]
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=range(1, len(dfs) + 1)) \
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True) \
       .rename_axis('File').reset_index()
print (df)
   File  Price Product
0     1      4       a
1     1      5       b
2     1      6       c
3     2      9       d
4     2      8       e
5     2      7       g
6     3      1       f
7     3      2       z
8     3      4       h
```

You can also use custom names from `list`:

```
dfs =   [df1,df2,df3]
names = ['file1','file2','file3']

df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=names)
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('File').reset_index()
print (df)
    File  Price Product
0  file1      4       a
1  file1      5       b
2  file1      6       c
3  file2      9       d
4  file2      8       e
5  file2      7       g
6  file3      1       f
7  file3      2       z
8  file3      4       h
```

Comment: Awesome! Please let me ask one more question. I have many .txt files in my folder. Concatenating those files by doing "dfs = [df1,df2, df3, df4, df5.....] is not a good idea. Is there any way to concatenate all files instead of this?

Comment: For example, I have 1000 .txt files in my folder. If I combine these .txt files by doing df1, df2, df3,...., it takes forever....